# can anyone explain to me the tsSmooth function in R?

Tags: r

can anyone explain to me the `tsSmooth` function in R?
I would like to use it to obtain a univariate time series with a linear trend

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried `?tsSmooth` ?

Comment: yes yes, but it didn't produce what I wanted. I'll explain my situation better by entering my code. `x<-rt(n=30,df=3, ncp=10)` `y<-rt(n=20,df=3, ncp=20)`  `myseries<-c(x,y,y2)` `tsSmooth<-c(x,y,y2)` `newseries<-tsSmooth` with the `st` command I created two random samples of a studend t. my `myseries` series will consist of these two champions. I wish the series would have a linear trend. with the command tsSmooth I can't. do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that on your code:

```
x<-rt(n=30,df=3, ncp=10)  
y<-rt(n=20,df=3,ncp=20) 
myseries<-c(x,y) 
tsSmooth<-c(x,y)  
newseries<-tsSmooth
```

you didn't apply the `tsSmooth()` function to your data. You simply created a vector named `tsSmooth` and another vector named `newseries`

`tsSmooth()` function uses a specific data input and doesn't provide much explanation.

There is this discussion that might help https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125946/generate-a-time-series-comprising-seasonal-trend-and-remainder-components-in-r

In addition, you could generate a simple trend using moving average. But I am not sure if it has all the statistical features you are looking for.

```
library("TTR")

plot.ts(myseries)
trendSMA <- SMA(myseries)
plot.ts(trendSMA)
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply, i will try to generate a trend using the moving average. Using the `tsSmooth` function gives me the following error `Error in UseMethod (" tsSmooth "):
  no applicable method for 'tsSmooth' applied to an object of class "c ('double', 'numeric')"`. I do not understand why

Comment: Hi, it seems this function requires a specific object (class of data). From tsSmooth documentation `object
a time-series fit. Currently only class "StructTS" is supported`.

Comment: yes, do you have any suggestions on how to reset my code? using the moving average code example I don't get what I want

Comment: Did you look at this:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125946/generate-a-time-series-comprising-seasonal-trend-and-remainder-components-in-r

Comment: yes but I don't think it's useful in my case. I would just like to change the trend of my time series and make it linear.

Comment: Not finding any code that is right for me, I would have thought of generating a time series with random values ​​and then sorting them in ascending order in order to have a linear trend. is this an adequate procedure? I paste the code  `x<-rt(n=30,df=3, ncp=10)`
`y<-rt(n=20,df=3, ncp=20)`
`y2<-rt(n=25, df=7,ncp=10)`
`y3<-rt(n=15, df=12, ncp=20)`
`myseries<-c(x,y,y2,y3)`
`newseries<-sort(myseries)`

Comment: I understood why the moving average code you indicated does not work in my case. after having prepared the time series with a linear trend, I implement the rsp command. with the method you have suggested there are some NAs that do not allow me to apply the rsp procedure.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are looking for. Your last code you concatenate 4 random t-distribution together and sorting them. I wouldn't consider that to be a series with a trend. There is no trend, it is random numbers (with fat tails!) in ascending order.
A linear trend is something like: Yt = constant (average) + slop * Xt. The slope is the trend. if you need a random trend you will add a random term.

Comment: I create a univariate time series by joining 2 random t distributions. I would like to set a linear trend for my time series, but I can't do it. I haven't found a room in r that gives me back what I want.

Comment: My problem is conceptual. You have a time series called `newseries`, ok.  You want to find a linear trend of this series?  A simple linear regression will fo it.
`df <- data.frame( x = 1:length(myseries), y = myseries) lm(y~x, df) # trend is 0.08469 `. I thought you wanted to create a time series with a trend.
To do that you would have to `y <- 3.14 + 1.55*myseries lm(y ~ myseries) # trend is 1.55`.